# Четные - нечетные (С++)

Tags: c++, оптимизация, арифметика, теория-чисел

Программа получает на вход два целых положительных числа A и B, не превосходящие 2×10^9.
Мне надо сделать оптимизацию, чтобы программа считывала разность четной и нечетной быстрее. Каким способом можно это сделать?.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a, b, sum = 0;
  cin >> a >> b;
  while (a<=b)
  {
    if (a % 2 == 0)
    {
      sum += a;
    }
    else
    {
      sum -= a;
    }
    a++;
  }
  cout << sum;
}
```

Comment: "программа считывала разность четной и нечетной" - ???

Comment: Непонятно, что вам нужно? Можете написать нормальным, русским языком?...

Comment: На бумажечке выпиши суммы и посмотри, что там получается...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, вобщем, *если то, что вы считаете, верно*, то его же можно посчитать как

```
((b+a)-(2*a-1)*(a%2)-(2*b+1)*(b%2))/2
```

вместо всех ваших циклов...

Вот так отработает без переполнения:

```
int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    int ca = a&1, cb = b&1;
    a >>= 1; b >>= 1;
    return b*(1-cb*2) + a*(1-ca*2) - cb;
}
```

Comment: Там int. На отрицательных тоже работает?

Comment: @Qwertiy Из условия: *два целых **положительных** числа A и B*...

Comment: Ну значит я невнимательный))) Но я бы делал `&1` вместо `%2`.

Comment: Ну, если 4 байта, то нужно unsigned переменные использовать (иначе в `(2 * a-1)` и `(2*b+1)`  быть переполнению при 2×10^9)

Comment: @avp Лучше брать `long long`, потому что результат может быть очень даже отрицательным...

Comment: @Harry, если обе не превышют 2млрд., то с unsigned int это выражение  верно посчитает (максимальный промежуточный результат будет 4000000001)

Comment: @avp Можно так переписать: `(b*(1-b%2*2) + a*(1-a%2*2) + (a%2 - b%2))/2`. Но смотрите, берем a = 7, b = 9. Должны получить -7+8-9=-8. Какой уж тут `unsigned`...

Comment: @avp См. дополненный ответ: так отработает без переполнения и в рамках `int`...

Comment: @Harry, здорово (жаль, плюсик у меня только один...)

Comment: @avp Забавно, что на таком на первый взгляд непритязательном вопросе можно столько придумать :)